# Java 8 stream, getting max() take long time for first time only

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have a `HashMap` which take `Integer` as a *Key* and array of Integer as a *value*, `HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>()`.

So I'm was trying to get the max values (array size) each time I loop on another array, e.g:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

result[i] = map.entrySet().stream().mapToInt(element -> element.getValue().size()).max().getAsInt() + 1;

long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();

long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

System.out.println( totalTime);
```

After I run this program several times on different inputs, I always get high latency on first time, e.g:

```
29 // <- First time
0
0
0
0
0
```

Using loops:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> element: map.entrySet()) {
     result[i] = result[i] < element.getValue().size() ? element.getValue().size() : result[i];
}


long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

System.out.println( "  " + totalTime);
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Of course it's a big problem on big inputs, so what is Wrong here?

Comment: I don't see why it is a duplicate of the other question. He is not trying to do a benchmark

Comment: Did you put your code in a for loop? Can you paste you fulll code.

Comment: @howie I will put it in for loop and post the result;

Comment: Your 2nd output seems to be constradictory!

Comment: @nullpointer what you mean?

Comment: @IbrahimAli Output `0
0
0
0
0
0` as compared to the output `29 // <- First time
0
0
0
0
0`.. there is no latency in the second run for the first iteration either. Anyway, if you're performing a benchmark, it's still better to do it in a proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because the JVM generates a new class on the fly when the Lambda is called for the first time. After that, this class can be reused. That's why you have a high latency on the first time.

Also, it's important to understand that Lambdas are not always the best options, specially for simple operations that could be done by using a good old loop. [This article](https://blog.codefx.org/java/stream-performance/) is rich and a pretty good reading for who is interested on Stream performance.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to replace it to basics loop for now, Also it will be good if documents provided for **JVM generates a new class on the fly**, Thank you~

Comment: Oh sure, sorry for not posting it. There is this article from the OpenJDK team explaining their strategy to translate lambdas into bytecode (Refer to the "Translation strategy" part): https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html

Comment: There is also this article with some in-depth analysis on how it works: https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood